# Subclass abstract method not being called

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I will post some code and then ask my question, because I think it needs some explaining.
So here is a basic representation of my superclass:

```
public abstract class ModeOfTransport {
    public abstract void updateView(String name);
}
```

Here are some examples of my subclasses:

```
public class Bus extends ModeOfTransport {
    @Override
    public void updateView(String stopName) {
        System.out.println("BUS");
    }
}

public class Train extends ModeOfTransport {
    @Override
    public void updateView(String stopName) {
        System.out.println("TRAIN");
    }
}
```

I have a `switch` that is meant to be able to decide which version of `updateView()` is called:

```
switch(transportType) {
    case BUS:
        handleInfo(new Bus());
        break;
    case TRAIN:
        handleInfo(new Train());
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

private void handleInfo(ModeOfTransport transportType) {
    transportType.updateView(name);
}
```

My goal is to print out either `TRAIN` or `BUS`. At the moment, it prints nothing! I'm guessing because it is calling the abstract method in the parent class, which has no body.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Also, as a side question, does this fall under `polymorphism` or `inheritance`?

Thanks!

Comment: Does handleInfo take one parameter or two? If you have two of them defined, one single parameter and one two parameter, you have overloading.

Comment: How many arguments are there in `handleInfo()` method?

Comment: Hi sorry, I edited my question. It was a direct copy and paste that i was trying to simplify for this question and just left in some superfluous stuff.

Comment: @eoinzy: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The code after edit looks just like duffymo's working example - is there still a problem?

Comment: The reason for the focus on issues like method naming is because an abstract method is not a method that exists but does nothing. It is a place holder for methods to be supplied by subclasses. The problem has to be something else, and not calling the method you intended to call is an obvious possibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made it work.  I have no idea what you're doing wrong, but perhaps you'll figure it out from this source code.

```
package transport;

/**
 * ModeOfTransport description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097153/java-subclass-abstract-method-not-being-called/14097167#14097153
 * @since 12/30/12 10:46 PM
 */
public abstract class ModeOfTransport {
    public abstract void updateView(String name);
}

package transport;

/**
 * Bus description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097153/java-subclass-abstract-method-not-being-called/14097167#14097153
 * @since 12/30/12 10:47 PM
 */
public class Bus extends ModeOfTransport {
    @Override
    public void updateView(String name) {
        System.out.println("BUS");
    }
}

package transport;

/**
 * Train description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 12/30/12 10:48 PM
 */
public class Train extends ModeOfTransport {
    @Override
    public void updateView(String name) {
        System.out.println("TRAIN");
    }
}


package transport;

/**
 * TransportVisitor description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097153/java-subclass-abstract-method-not-being-called/14097167#14097153
 * @since 12/30/12 10:49 PM
 */
public class TransportVisitor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TransportVisitor visitor = new TransportVisitor();
        String [] types = { "TRAIN", "BUS" };
        for (String type : types) {
            visitor.updateView(type);
        }
    }

    public void updateView(String transportTypeName) {
        switch(transportTypeName) {
            case "BUS":
                handleInfo(new Bus());
                break;
            case "TRAIN":
                handleInfo(new Train());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void handleInfo(ModeOfTransport transportType) {
        transportType.updateView((String) null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, apologies. That was a typo on my part. Edited now.

Comment: One thing where this doesn't match the OP's code is that yours switches on strings, and his switches on class names.

Comment: Yup, figured it out. Was my own fault for leaving the `default` case blank and not catching an incorrectly passed type.

Comment: @eoinzy Could you post that as the answer, and accept it, and add context to the question to clarify why this was happening? Because the code above has all types accounted for.

Answer (score 2):

You have inconsistently named methods. Your base class has `updateView`, but your derived classes have `updateWebView` Also, since you aren't using any of the base classes methods yet, this would fall under polymorphism, which means you  could use an interface if you wanted.

Comment: Hi sorry, see my comment above. The inconsistent method names were a typo on my part.